# Django form not returning validation error even when it is supposed to?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, validationerror

In the console I can see that it has printed the "Less" string, that means the control is going inside the "if len(f_N) < 2", but then the validation error is not printed. Please help me out on whats wrong with the code.

####My forms.py file:####

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    GENDER=[('male','MALE'),('female','FEMALE')]  
    firstName= forms.CharField()
    lastName= forms.CharField()
    email= forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput,required=False,initial='Youremail@xmail.com')
    address=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    gender=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=GENDER))
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    ssn=forms.IntegerField()

    def clean_firstName(self):
        f_N=self.cleaned_data['firstName']
        print(f_N)
        if len(f_N)>15:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Max length allowed is 15 characters')
        if len(f_N) < 2:
            print(len(f_N))
            print("less")
            raise forms.ValidationError('Min length showuld be 2 characters')

        else:
            print("end")
            return f_N
```

#######My html file######

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>User Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> User Registration</h1>

  <table>
  <form method="post">
    
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.as_table}}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

##########My views.py file##########

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
from .models import User
# Create your views here.
def UserRegistrationView(request):
    form=UserRegistrationForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form_1=UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form_1.is_valid() :    
            #print(form_1.cleaned_data)
            form_1=form_1.cleaned_data 
            print(request.POST)
            print(form_1)
            user_1=User()
            user_1.firstName=form_1['firstName']
            user_1.lastName = form_1['lastName']
            user_1.email = form_1['email']
            user_1.save()
        
    return render(request,'formsDemo/userRegistration.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to this topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

in your `forms.py` you imported `ValidationError` the right way with `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError` but then you are raising it the wrong way in your function `clean_firstName()`, it should be

```
    raise ValidationError('..')
```

and NOT

```
    raise forms.ValidationError('..')
```

#### Update

in your `views.py`, since you have `form_1=UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)` then you should pass `form_1` to the context in `render` statement and NOT `form`. Any way you can do things the proper way (and you won't need the second `form_1` anymore):

```py
def UserRegistrationView(request):

    form=UserRegistrationForm()

    if request.method=='POST':

        form=UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()

            # Note: 
            # 1. if it happens 'form.is_valide()' returns false, then you'll
            # get the errors in 'form.errors' bag.
            # 2. you don't need to import User Model since you are using 'formMdel'

            # maybe you need to redirect to home page if you successfully saved
            # the new user .. display a flash message .. 

    return render(request,'formsDemo/userRegistration.html',{'form':form})
```

refer to this tuto https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/

Comment: Tried your suggestion. But still facing the same issue. No errors in the browser.

Comment: @ArghyaBhattacharya i updated my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: @cizaro Added this snippet in the template. Still no show of error. I am using Django 3.1.4 if that matters.

Comment: The 2nd Update worked. Now its working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the form error(s) like this:

```py
   def clean_firstName(self):
        f_N=self.cleaned_data['firstName']
        print(f_N)
        if len(f_N)>15:
            self.add_error('firstName', 'Max length allowed is 15 characters')
        if len(f_N) < 2:
            print(len(f_N))
            print("less")
            self.add_error('firstName', 'Min length showuld be 2 characters')

        else:
            print("end")
            return f_N
```

and also make sure the cleaned `firstName` is always returned, because with youe current code, it won't be returned for some paths. So to cover this issue, just add a `return f_N` outside all the `if`s.